# twitter bootstrap btn-nav always showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

anybody had an idea why the btn-nav supposed to show only when the screen is down sized is always showing in my page. here is the code:

```
<div class="nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="./index.html">Bootstrap</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Extentions" -> "Module manager". Find your module and edit it. On tab "Options" ->"Advanced parameters" clear inputs "Menu Class Suffix" and "Module Class Suffix". Click "Save" and enjoy it.